# how to add an optional argument to a slash command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how can i add an optional argument so for example 'thing_to_say' is optional

```
@client.tree.command(name="say", description = "whats should the bot say")
@app_commands.describe(thing_to_say = "text")
async def say(interaction: discord.Interaction, thing_to_say: str):
    if not interaction.user.guild_permissions.administrator:
      return await interaction.response.send_message("You requre administator permisions to use this command")
    if len(thing_to_say) != 0:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'{thing_to_say}')
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'nothing to be said')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple, really.

Option 1: You use the `typing.Optional` as a type hint for `thing_to_say`:

```py
async def ...(..., thing_to_say: typing.Optional[str], ...):
```

Option 2: Using the `|` with `None` as a typehint:

```py
async def ...(..., thing_to_say: str | None, ...):
```

[`typing.Optional` Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

Comment: thank you so much i was looking for such a long time and could never find the right thing.

Comment: Alternatively, you can set the parameter to have a default value. `thing_to_say="hi"`

Comment: I don't think that actually works for @app_commands